# My php Table code is not working

Tags: php, html

So, I was just trying some things, and I wanted to do a table, but when I try to run it, it gives me an error in this part of the code:
echo '

```
echo '
<table border = 1 width = 300px>
<tr>
<td> Name:
</td>
<td '.$Contacts[$Index]['Name']>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone:
</td>
<td '.$Contacts[$Index]['Phone number']>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Email:
</td>
<td '.$Contacts[$Index]['email']>
</td>
</tr>
';
```

Can someone please tell me if there is anything wrong I am not seeing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post the complete error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenation is not done properly.

```
<?php
echo '
<table border = 1 width = 300px>
<tr>
<td> Name:
</td>
<td>' . $Contacts[$Index]['Name'] .'
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Phone:
</td>
<td>' . $Contacts[$Index]['Phone number'] . '
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Email:
</td>
<td>'. $Contacts[$Index]['email'] . '
</td>
</tr>
';
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your concatenation. I would prefer you close your php tags, output simple html and use php to echo variables when required. It will keep the code clean. Here is an example

```
?>

<table border = 1 width = 300px>
<tr>
    <td> Name:</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Contacts[$Index]['Name']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Phone:</td>
    <td><?php echo $Contacts[$Index]['Phone number']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Email:</td>
    <td> <?php echo $Contacts[$Index]['email'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
```

There is another error that you are add values as `<td value></td>` while the correct way is `<td>value<td>`
I have resolved that issue.